# Mac OS - Run VS Code with admin privileges so the changes can be applied

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't reload ou enable the custom css and js extension at VSCode.

A warning show up:

> "Run VS Code with admin privileges so the changes can be applied"

and I just cannot enable to use the synthwave84 extension, who customized my vscode.

This is my `settings.json`:

```
"vscode_custom_css.imports": [
 "file:///Users/myuser/Documents/synthwave84.css",
 "file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/theme/custom.css",
 "file:///Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/theme/custom.js"
],
 "vscode_custom_css.policy": true
]
```

Comment: Did you ever get this working? Even if I `sudo code .` it still does not work.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think you just have to run VS Code with admin privileges. I found this article that explains how you can do that.

https://www.wikihow.com/Open-Applications-With-Root-Privileges-on-a-Mac

Answer (score 0):

Running into the exact same problem when updating Synthwave...

Here is what worked for me. 
To give the permission to the extensions:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) ~/.vscode/extensions
```

And then open VS code as Admin:

```
sudo /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
```